# Can you explain this code about recursion in linked list

Tags: recursion, linked-list

The problem is to add two linked list like an addition of integer. This is the sum function in the problem.

n1 and n2 are the head nodes of two lists, which is to be added into l3. Now in this code i don't understand the recursion part.

In a normal recursion like fibonacci or factorial we have a condition in code saying when recursion should end. Here there is no such condition. Can you explain on how it ends.

```
    int addNode(Node* n1,Node* n2,List* l3)
    {
        if(n1==NULL)
              return 0;
        int carry=addNode(n1->getNode(),n2->getNode(),l3);
        int val=carry+n1->getdata()+n2->getdata();
        int carry1=val/10;
        int quot=val%10;
        l3->prepend(quot);
        return carry1;
    }
```

Comment: "*we have a condition in code saying when recursion should end. Here there is no such condition.*". Here it is   `if(n1==NULL)
              return 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comments:

`if(n1==NULL)` is the condition that stops the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the Fibonacci recursion, it works in a similar way in terms of stopping the recursion.

This is a code snippet for a fibonacci

```
int fibonacci(int n)  {
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(n == 1)
      return 1;
    else
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Notice how there is a condition that checks `if (n == 0)` it's same logic as what you have being `if (n1 == NULL)`and in both cases, you `return 0` which would break out of the method.

Once this happens, the recursion goes upwards, this means that for each iteration, the rest of the method is invoked exiting with a return. In your example, the `carry1` is returned.